Propensity Score Matching with Python
im currently try to automate an evaluation process for my company. In the Past the whole process would take at least nearly 2 Weeks in total and i managed to automate everything, that you need at least 1 day for the whole process without Quality control.
A former ex colleage left his R Scripts behind and i managed to write an Python script based on the R PSM Script but the outcome is different, nearly identical. I used the same Data for the R PSM Skript and my Python PSM Skript. The Database is stored on a db2 table:
Python Script:
import pandas as pd
from connection import MetaData, cursor1, connection1
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors # KNN
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import os

### DB Connection in connection.py

metadata = MetaData()

# Connextion to Database
engine = define_connection2()

# SQL-Query
sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1'

# Process the Query
with engine.connect() as connection:

    dataSample_all = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)

dataSample = dataSample_all.copy()

# Convert factors to numeric values
for col in dataSample.columns:
    if dataSample[col].dtype == 'object':
        dataSample[col] = pd.to_numeric(dataSample[col].str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce')

# Calculate total cost SA700
dataSample['G'] = dataSample[['BETRAG_ARZT_VJ', 'BETRAG_ZAHNARZT_VJ', 'BETRAG_APOTHEKE_VJ', 
                              'BETRAG_KRKHS_VJ', 'BETRAG_SONST_VJ', 'BETRAG_DIALYSE_VJ', 
                              'BETRAG_DMP_VJ', 'BETRAG_KRGELD_VJ', 'BETRAG_KRGELD_KIND_VJ']].sum(axis=1)

# Define variables
Tr = dataSample['TN']
Y = dataSample['G']
X = dataSample[[
'KV_1','KV_2','KV_3','KV_4','KV_5','KV_6','KV_7','KV_8','KV_9','KV_10','KV_11','KV_12','KV_13','KV_14','KV_15','KV_16',....

<-- other variables -->

....,'KNR360_Nr234','PFLEGE_NR1','PFLEGE_NR2','PFLEGE_NR3','PFLEGE_NR4','PFLEGE_NR5'
]] # 285 Attributes

# Logistic regression to calculate propensity scores
logit_model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1500, solver='saga', random_state=32)
logit_model.fit(X, Tr)
propensity_scores = logit_model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]

# Indices for treated and control group
treated_indices = np.where(Tr == 1)[0]
control_indices = np.where(Tr == 0)[0]

# Nearest Neighbors for the control group (KNN)
nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)
nn.fit(propensity_scores[control_indices].reshape(-1, 1))

# Finding the nearest neighbors for the treatment group
distances, indices = nn.kneighbors(propensity_scores[treated_indices].reshape(-1, 1))

# Define caliper value
caliper = 0.02

# Filter pairs within the caliper
valid_matches = distances.flatten() <= caliper
matched_treated_indices = treated_indices[valid_matches]
matched_control_indices = control_indices[indices.flatten()[valid_matches]]

# Combination of the matched indices
matched_indices = np.concatenate([matched_treated_indices, matched_control_indices])

# Filtered data for matching
matched_data = dataSample.iloc[matched_indices]

# Count and sort the number of occurrences in TN
print(matched_data['TN'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False))

R Script:
Calculate total cost SA700:
G<-BETRAG_ARZT_VJ+BETRAG_ZAHNARZT_VJ+BETRAG_APOTHEKE_VJ+BETRAG_KRKHS_VJ+BETRAG_SONST_VJ+BETRAG_DIALYSE_VJ+BETRAG_DMP_VJ+BETRAG_KRGELD_VJ+BETRAG_KRGELD_KIND_VJ


#Define variables
##Treatment variable
Tr <- cbind(TN)
##Outcome
Y <- cbind(G)  
##Predictors
#X <- cbind(ALTERSKLASSE,ICD_Dauer,Schweregrad)  
X <- cbind(KV_1,KV_2,KV_3,KV_4,KV_5,KV_6,KV_7,KV_8,KV_9,KV_10,KV_11,KV_12,KV_13,KV_14,KV_15,KV_16,...

<-- other variables -->

....,KNR360_Nr234,PFLEGE_NR1,PFLEGE_NR2,PFLEGE_NR3,PFLEGE_NR4,PFLEGE_NR5)

##Regression
glm1 <- glm(Tr ~ X, family = binomial, data = dataSample)
summary(glm1)

##PSM-Matching
psm.out <- Match(Y=NULL, Tr=Tr, X=glm1$fitted, estimand="ATT", M=1, caliper=0.02, ties=FALSE, replace=TRUE)
summary(psm.out)

##Matching partner:
partner <- rbind(cbind(psm.out$index.treated,psm.out$index.control),cbind(psm.out$index.control,psm.out$index.treated))
Partner_index <-partner[,1]

##PSM-Result
psm_erg <-dataSample[Partner_index,c(1:3,32)]

#summary(psm_erg)

psm_erg %>% count(TN, sort = TRUE)

So far, i get the same Treatment groups to the Control Group. I also get an error that the 'max_iter=1500' was reached. Where did i made the Mistake or is there another package i can use for PSM?
Edited
I get the exact Treatment and Control Group, that's not normal. Especially together with the same message of the max_iter! Setting the max_iter higher doesn't get me a better result at all.

Hard to tell without a reproducible example. However, assignments like X <- cbind(KV_1,KV_2,...) won't return what you probably expect them to return, unless you have unnecessarily attached dataSample to your search path. Since your code relies on package {dplyr} anyway, see the documentation on how to select columns, join dataframes etc. with minimal hazzle.

The R Code is not from me like I wrote in the beginning.

The error comes from logit_model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1500, solver='saga', random_state=32. You can just raise the max_iter?

I did from 500 to 1000 and than to 1500 and still get the max_iter error.
